# Facebook app custom data database

Tags: database, facebook, nosql

Does facebook provide a way to store custom data for an app? I think of a user related store just like the users folder in operating systems. Performance should not be an issue as I can hold the data in memcache over a session but leave the persistent data at facebook so I don't have to store userdata on my servers.

Comment: custom data for an app? Can you give an example?

Comment: For games there are all kinds of data. Achievements, experience points ect.

Comment: i need a simple counter for the app i am working on. dying to get some responses on this question.

Answer (score 0):

There's no storage available on Facebook's server for your app to use.  See http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=100552270038780